# Screen keeps terminating

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am trying to run a script in a screen that uses `inotifywait` to check for new files being created and then runs a script when an event that matches some parameters occurs. For some reason screen keeps terminating even though the script being run is looped.

I start the screen with screen -d -m -S scriptname //path to .sh and the looped part of the script look like this

```
#start folder monitoring
while fileevent=$(inotifywait -rq -e create $path_to_monitor); do CheckFileEvent; done
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop of your run depend from the result of your assignment, try this:

```
while :;do
    fileevent=$(inotifywait -rq -e create $path_to_monitor)
    CheckFileEvent
  done
```